# script by eval became stuck on react native version 0.63.1 (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, event-handling, eval

"react-native": "0.63.1"

I have some dynamic javascript run using eval in react native iOS.  If the same code is not wrapped in eval, it works fine but if executed by eval it became stuck and I had to tap on the phone screen or rock/shake the phone to have the script execution resumed.  The stuck place boils down to the following call in WebView.ios.js ("react-native-webview": "^10.8.3"):

```
     _this.injectJavaScript = function (data) {
          UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(_this.getWebViewHandle(), _this.getCommands().injectJavaScript, [data]);
          console.log('injectJavaScript5 dispatched', data); // instrumented
     }
```

That dispatch call actually finished as I can see the log 'injectJavaScript5 dispatched' printed:
[dispatchViewManagerCommand logs are from instrumenting node_modules/react-native/React/Modules/RCTUIManager.m:  RCTLogWarn(@"dispatchViewManagerCommand start");]

```
2020-09-07 11:24:34.463462-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] 'injectJavaScript5 dispatched', 
----- !!! 9 seconds nothing happened until tap/rock/shake the phone
2020-09-07 11:24:43.378875-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand start
2020-09-07 11:24:43.379158-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand before block start
2020-09-07 11:24:43.379336-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass before
2020-09-07 11:24:43.379532-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass after
2020-09-07 11:24:43.379711-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass Number method before
2020-09-07 11:24:43.379876-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass Number method after
2020-09-07 11:24:43.380040-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass args before
2020-09-07 11:24:43.380209-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass args after
2020-09-07 11:24:43.380424-0400 myapp[810:120363] [native] dispatchViewManagerCommand end
2020-09-07 11:24:43.383301-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand start
2020-09-07 11:24:43.386167-0400 myapp[810:117952] [native] injectJavasScript3 start:
---- why dispatchViewManagerCommand logs are in both [native] and [javascript]?
2020-09-07 11:24:34.335216-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand before block start
2020-09-07 11:24:34.351613-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass before
2020-09-07 11:24:34.371906-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass after
2020-09-07 11:24:34.381274-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass Number method before
2020-09-07 11:24:34.390347-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass Number method after
2020-09-07 11:24:34.397696-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass args before
2020-09-07 11:24:34.405117-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand managerCLass args after
2020-09-07 11:24:34.410255-0400 myapp[810:118124] [javascript] dispatchViewManagerCommand end
```

1. Both react-native-webview and react-native-wkwebview-reborn are tried, same stuck behavior.
2. Both hooks and classes are tried, same stuck behavior.
3. react native 0.57.2 works fine with classes (hooks NOT tried), i.e. script execution NOT stuck.
4. not every call is stuck, some calls are ok, others are stuck,
5. There was one time I switched from WiFi to LTE, the script ran smoothly several times and I thought the problem is with WiFi.  But once I kill and restart the app, the same stuck behaviour returned.
6. I suspect the event queue/loop somehow is affected by eval as tap/rock/shake the phone all generates some events.  But where to check?  Is this a bug in RN or a security feature?

BTW what does myapp[810:118124] mean?  I know myapp is the app name but 810:118124?

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried using Function, it didn't help.

Comment: the behaviour seems to be consistent with https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19572 but both eval directly and Function have the same pausing behaviour and 0.57.2 was working consistently and flawlessly.

Comment: transpile async/await into regenerator code makes the problem go away.  Now I need to transpile on the fly in react native app.

Comment: transpile using https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone: `const Babel = require('@babel/standalone'); var code = Babel.transform(script, { plugins: ['transform-async-to-generator'] }).code;`

Comment: @babel/standalone works fine in Simulator and debug.  Release build crashes in iOS (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12124).  The workaround is described in the babel issue 12124.